# How to get rid of Distributed Denial of Service or mining happening on my Linux box

Tags: init, ddos, strace, superuser, pstree

Some strange processing running and eating up all resource. 
I'd killed it many times but still its coming up and starting again.
Highly appreciate your help!

Here is the pstree output for reference:

```
$ pstree -s
init─┬─-bash
     ├─-bash───1023*[{-bash}]
     ├─agetty
     ├─atd
     ├─auditd───{auditd}
     ├─crond
     ├─dbus-daemon
     ├─dhclient
     ├─irqbalance
     ├─java───311*[{java}]
     ├─java───81*[{java}]
     ├─java───55*[{java}]
     ├─6*[mingetty]
     ├─ntpd
     ├─rngd
     ├─rpc.statd
     ├─rpcbind
     ├─rsyslogd───3*[{rsyslogd}]
     ├─2*[sendmail]
     ├─sensu-client───{sensu-client}
     ├─sshd─┬─sshd───sshd───bash───sudo───su───bash
     │      ├─2*[sshd───sshd───bash]
     │      ├─sshd───sshd───bash───sudo───su───bash───tail
     │      └─sshd───sshd───bash───pstree
     ├─udevd───2*[udevd]
     └─yMPzpi───9*[{yMPzpi}]
```

**yMPzpi** : This is one one which is starting again with different name even after killing it.

Here strace output for reference:

```
$ strace -p 294891
Process 294891 attached
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...>) = 1
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 300000) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1540834737, 507976501}) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 60000) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(4, "{\"id\":1,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"error\":"..., 2044, 0, NULL, NULL) = 63
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1540834737, 508379955}) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 90000) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 300000) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1540834778, 177325012}) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 60000) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(4, "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"job\","..., 2044, 0, NULL, NULL) = 253
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1540834778, 177412756}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1540834778, 177475706}) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 90000) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 300000) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1540834846, 399415744}) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 60000) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(4, "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"job\","..., 2044, 0, NULL, NULL) = 253
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1540834846, 399486835}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1540834846, 399551309}) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 90000 
^CProcess 294891 detached
 <detached ...>
```

Comment: I'm happy to provide and run whatever you need, but please help to get-rid of this issue. Appreciate your help!

Comment: This question should be moved to [su]

Comment: Okay.tx doing it.

Comment: @NineBerry , Created under superuser [link] (https://superuser.com/questions/1371147/how-to-get-rid-of-distributed-denial-of-service-or-mining-happening-on-my-linux)